# need conky formatting help to align grep output

Tags: conky

I can't figure this out, so i hope you guys can give me a hand here.
So, i was trying to figure a way to show the TLP status on my conky.
In the terminal you would type: **tlp-stat -s**

However....that's too much info, i just want the current status part. The way i tried to do it in conky, is like this:

${exec tlp-stat -s |grep 'battery\|AC'}

now, this works perfectly, when i plug/unplugg the charger, it changes accordingly, but.. the lines are not properly aligned!

[conky screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6nDY.png)

See? How is it possible to align this to match the rest of my theme?
thanks in advance
here's the config:

> conky.config = {
>
> --Various settings
>
> background = true,                          -- forked to background     cpu_avg_samples =
>   2,                        -- The number of samples to average for CPU monitoring.
>     diskio_avg_samples = 10,                    -- The number of samples to average for
>   disk I/O monitoring.  double_buffer = true,                       -- Use the Xdbe
>   extension? (eliminates flicker)   if_up_strictness = 'address',               --
>   how strict if testing interface is up - up, link or address
>     net_avg_samples = 2,                        -- The number of samples to average for net
>   data  no_buffers = true,                          -- Subtract (file system) buffers from
>   used memory?  temperature_unit = 'celsius',               -- fahrenheit or
>   celsius   text_buffer_size = 2048,                    -- size of buffer for display of
>   content of large variables - default 256  update_interval = 1,                        --
>   update interval   imlib_cache_size = 0,                       --
>   disable image cache to get a new spotify cover per song
>
> --Placement
>
> alignment = 'top_right',                        --
>   top_left,top_middle,top_right,bottom_left,bottom_middle,bottom_right,
>                                                 -- middle_left,middle_middle,middle_right,none  --Arch Duoscreen    --gap_x = -1910,    gap_x = 15,                                 -- pixels between
>   right or left border  gap_y = 15,                                 -- pixels between bottom or
>   left border   minimum_height = 600,                       -- minimum height of window
>     minimum_width = 300,                        -- minimum height of window     maximum_width
>   = 300,                        -- maximum height of window
>
> --Graphical
>
> border_inner_margin = 10,                   -- margin between border and text
>     border_outer_margin = 5,                    -- margin between border and edge of
>   window    border_width = 0,                           -- border width in pixels
>     default_bar_width = 80,                 -- default is 0 - full width
>     default_bar_height = 10,                    -- default is 6     default_gauge_height =
>   25,                   -- default is 25    default_gauge_width =40,                    -- default is
>   40    default_graph_height = 40,                  -- default is 25
>     default_graph_width = 0,                    -- default is 0 - full width
>     default_shade_color = '#000000',            -- default shading colour
>     default_outline_color = '#000000',          -- default outline colour
>     draw_borders = false,                       -- draw borders around text
>     draw_graph_borders = true,                  -- draw borders around graphs
>     draw_shades = false,                        -- draw shades  draw_outline =
>   false,                        -- draw outline     stippled_borders = 0,                       -- dashing the
>   border
>
> --Textual
>
> extra_newline = false,                      -- extra newline at the end - for
>   asesome's wiboxes     format_human_readable = true,               -- KiB, MiB rather
>   then number of bytes  font = 'Roboto Mono:size=10',               -- font for
>   complete conky unless in code defined     max_text_width = 0,                         -- 0
>   will make sure line does not get broken if width too smal
>     max_user_text = 16384,                      -- max text in conky default 16384
>     override_utf8_locale = true,                -- force UTF8 requires xft
>     short_units = true,                         -- shorten units from KiB to k
>     top_name_width = 21,                        -- width for $top name value default 15
>     top_name_verbose = false,                   -- If true, top name shows the full
>   command line of  each  process - Default value is false.  uppercase =
>   false,                            -- uppercase or not     use_spacer = 'none',                        -- adds
>   spaces around certain objects to align - default none     use_xft =
>   true,                             -- xft font - anti-aliased font     xftalpha = 1,                               --
>   alpha of the xft font - between 0-1
>
> --Windows
>
> own_window = true,                          -- create your own window to draw
>     own_window_argb_value = 0,              -- real transparency - composite
>   manager required 0-255    own_window_argb_visual = true,              -- use ARGB
>   - composite manager required  own_window_colour = '#000000',              -- set colour if own_window_transparent no  own_window_hints =
>   'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',  -- if own_window
>   true - just hints - own_window_type sets it   own_window_transparent =
>   false,                -- if own_window_argb_visual is true sets background opacity
>   0%    own_window_title = 'system_conky',          -- set the name manually  -
>   default conky "hostname"  own_window_type = 'desktop',                -- if
>   own_window true options are: normal/override/dock/desktop/panel
>
> --Colours
>
> default_color = '#CB9D7A',                  -- default color and border color
>     color1 = '#FF0000',     color2 = '#C17D12',     color3 = '#cccccc',     color4
>   = '#D9BC83',  color5 = '#BF4E0C',     color6 = '#FFFFFF',
>
> --Signal Colours    color7 = '#1F7411',                         --green     color8 =
>   '#FFA726',                        --orange    color9 = '#F1544B',                         --firebrick
>
> ```
> --Lua
> ```
>
> };
>
> conky.text = [[
>
> ${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}${voffset 10}S Y S T E M   ${hr
>   2}${font}${color} ${color2}${voffset 8}Hostname:${color}
>   ${alignr}${nodename} ${color2}Distro:${color}${alignr}${alignr}${execi
>   999999 lsb_release -ds} ${color2}Kernel:${color}${alignr}${exec uname}
>   ${exec uname -r} ${color2}Nvidia Driver: ${color}${alignr}${execi
>   60000 nvidia-smi | grep "Driver Version"| awk {'print $3'}}
>   ${color2}Uptime:${color} ${alignr}${uptime}
>
> ${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}T E M P E R A T U R E S  ${hr
>   2}${font}${color} ${color2}CPU Temp:${color} $alignr${execi 10 sensors
>   | grep 'Core 0' | awk {'print $3'}} ${color2}GPU Temp ${color}
>   ${alignr}${execi 60 nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu
>   --format=csv,noheader} °C
>
> ${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}P R O C E S S O R S  ${hr
>   2}${font}${color} ${color2}CPU Freq:${color} $alignr${freq}MHz
>
> ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 1:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu1}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu1} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 2:${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu2}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu2}
>   ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 3:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu3}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu3} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 4:${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu4}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu4}
>   ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 5:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu5}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu5} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 6:${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu6}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu6}
>   ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 7:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu7}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu7} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 8:${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu8}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu8}
>   ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 9:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu9}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu9} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core
>   10:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu10}%${alignr}${cpubar
>   cpu10} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 11:${color} ${alignr}${offset
>   -10}${cpu cpu11}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu11} ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Core 12:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu cpu12}%${alignr}${cpubar
>   cpu12}
>
> ${color2}${offset 20}CPU Total:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${cpu
>   cpu0}%${alignr}${cpubar cpu0}
>
> ${color5}${offset 20}Governor:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${execi 5
>   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor}
>
> ${color2}Top Processes${goto 222}CPU%${goto 274} ${voffset 4}
>   ${color2} 1  -  ${top name 1}${alignr}${goto 170} ${goto
>   222}${color}${top cpu 1}    ${color2} 2  -  ${top name 2}${alignr}
>   ${goto 222}${color}${top cpu 2} ${goto 274}   ${color2} 3  -  ${top
>   name 3}${alignr} ${goto 222}${color}${top cpu 3} ${goto 274}
>   ${color2} 4  -  ${top name 4}${alignr} ${goto 222}${color}${top cpu 4}
>   ${goto 274}   ${color2} 5  -  ${top name 5}${alignr} ${goto
>   222}${color}${top cpu 5} ${goto 274}
>
> ${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}D R I V E S   ${hr 2}${font}${color}
>   ${offset 30}${color2}SSD:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${fs_used /} /
>   ${fs_size /}${alignr}${fs_used_perc /} % ${offset
>   30}${color2}HDD:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${fs_used /home} /
>   ${fs_size /home}${alignr}${fs_used_perc /home} %
>
> ${color5}${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}N E T W O R K   ${hr
>   2}${font}${color} ${color2}${offset 30}IP Address: ${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10$}${addrs wlo1}
>
> ${color5}${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}B A T T E R Y   ${hr
>   2}${font}${color} ${color2}${offset 30}Time Left: ${color}
>   ${alignr}${offset -10$}${battery_time BAT0} ${color2}${offset
>   30}State: ${color} ${alignr}${offset -10$}$Battery
>
> ${color5}${color5}${font Roboto:size=10}T L P  ${hr 2}${font}${color}
>   ${color2}${offset 30}Status:${color} ${alignr}${offset -10}${exec
>   tlp-stat -s |grep 'battery\|AC'}
>
> ]];

Answer (score 0):

There are probably numerous ways to achieve what you want but personally I use `sed` and `awk` for this sort of string manipulation. (These are not conky tools).

So say the output you expect is `Power source   = AC` then the actual item you are interested in is the fourth value (space separated values) so an awk command to return only the fourth value would be:

`tlp-stat -s |grep 'battery\|AC' |awk '{print $4}'`

So you can use that form to output what you need along with conky alignment commands such as `{alignr 80}` or whatever you need to align text/values etc.

sed and awk are powerful string scanning/manipulation tools - have a look at the man pages and do online searches for what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! 
Solved like this:

> ${color2}Mode:${color} ${exec tlp-stat -s |grep 'Mode' |awk '{print
>   $3}' } ${color2}Power Source:${color} ${exec tlp-stat -s |grep
>   'source' |awk '{print $4}' }

Here is the final result!

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQq8q.png)